# Get key, value pair for nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

how would I convert the following nested dictionary to a single dictionary

```
status = {'data': {'isFault': False, 'isButton': False, 'battery': 'NORMAL', 'powerInput': 'NOT_PRESENT', 'powerInput5vIo': 'NOT_PRESENT'}, 'error': 'NO_ERROR'}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
new_status = {'isFault': False, 'isButton': False, 'battery': 'NORMAL', 'powerInput': 'NOT_PRESENT', 'powerInput5vIo': 'NOT_PRESENT', 'error': 'NO_ERROR'}

for k, v in status['data'].items():
    print (k, ":", v)
```

I managed to extract the key, value pairs from 'data' but I'm stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert this nested dictionary into one single dictionary in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557213/how-to-convert-this-nested-dictionary-into-one-single-dictionary-in-python-3)

Comment: ran the above answer with `print(func(status))` yields your desired dictionary result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert nested dictionary into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905359/convert-nested-dictionary-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to preserve the inner dictionary or are you free to mutate it. If the latter, just extract it and use it as a base adding in the missing members:

```
inner = status['data']
del status['data']
inner.update(**status)
result = inner
```

Note, if any keys occur in both the inner and outer dict, the outer overwrites the inner key with the code above. If you need to not modify it in-place, just copy it first:

```
from copy import copy

temp = copy(status)
inner = temp['data']
del temp['data']
inner.update(**temp)
result = inner
```

And finally, if inner should take precedence over outer, then reverse the last statement:

```
temp.update(**inner)
result = temp
```

And you have your result.